# Do it in proc sql

Tags: sas

How to do below codes in proc sql.
Two proc statement and one merge given below.

```
 proc sort data=new out=new1 nodupkey;
 by id;
 where roll=100;
 run;

 proc sort data new2 out =new4 nodupkey
 by id;
 where roll=100;
 run;

 data score;
 merge new4 (in=a) new1;
 by id;
 if a;
 run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The merge you show is equivalent to SQL left-join.  You want all the rows from "new2" and ignore all the rows from "new" that don't have a common id.  The uniqueness of the id (per the pre-sorts) further supports a left-join equivalence.

```
Proc SQL;
  select new.*, new2.* 
  from new2
  left join new on new.id = new2.id
  where roll=100
  order by id;
quit;
```

For the scenario of atypical data where there is many:many ids in the merge, the left-join is not equivalent.

I did leave out the NODUPKEY equivalent. Presuming option EQUALS is in effect, the selection of a groups first row would be equivalent.  The undocumented MONOTONIC() function can be used to apply a default row order to a sub-query, which can then be used in a by group having expression.

```
data LEFT;
  input id x1 x2 x3;
  datalines;
1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 
1 3 3 3
2 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5
;
run;

data RIGHT;
  input id  y1 y2 y3 x1;
datalines;
1 1 1 1 11
2 1 1 1 22
3 1 2 3 4
3 2 3 4 5
3 3 4 5 6
4 1 1 1 44
6 6 6 6 6
;
run;

proc sql; 
  select
    LEFT.id
  , coalesce(RIGHT.x1,LEFT.x1) as x1
  , LEFT.x2
  , LEFT.x3
  , RIGHT.y1
  , RIGHT.y2
  , RIGHT.y3
  from
  ( 
    select * from (select monotonic() as _seq_, * from LEFT) group by id having _seq_ = min(_seq_)
  ) 
  as LEFT

  left join

  (
    select * from (select monotonic() as _seq_, * from RIGHT) group by id having _seq_ = min(_seq_)
  )
  as RIGHT

  on
    LEFT.id = RIGHT.id
  ;
```

I feel the need to reiterate that SQL left join is not always the same a merge, and SQL does not have common variable 'overlaying' that is implicit in DATA Step.  When LEFT and RIGHT collide on non-key variables, you need to select a coalescence of the common variables into a new like-named variable in the output.